# group by with order by desc

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select aaa.BookId from
(SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Id, BookId,CreatedOnUtc
                       FROM          dbo.Chapter AS c
                       ORDER BY CreatedOnUtc desc             
                       ) as aaa
group by aaa.BookId
```

how come ORDER BY CreatedOnUtc desc doesn't not have any effect on the result.

I want to get a result like this

```
BookId    (with desc createdonUtc)
3
4
1
...
```

UPDATED: i go with this

```
select BookId, Max(CreatedOnUtc)
from Chapter
group by BookId
order by Max(CreatedOnUtc) desc
```

Comment: Ordering should only be done OUTSIDE subqueries, meaning only in the main query.

Comment: What's the sense of selecting the top 100% percent?

Comment: sorry wrong question... i meant... why do you need to group by a column without having sth to show near to your select statement that utilizes the group by statement?

Answer (score 2):

The ORDER BY is only for your subquery. Your outer query has no order by clause, so the result can be in any order.

Other things:

- Why `TOP 100 PERCENT`?
- Why `SELECT BookId` and `GROUP BY BookId` but no aggregating column? Maybe you just want `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Also, what you want to achieve might not be possible. If you have this table with a duplicate BookId:

```
ID BookId CreatedOnUtc
1  1      1
2  2      2
3  1      3
```

In what order shall your result be? 1 2 or 2 1?

Comment: sorry for my knowledge. fool me, i think distinct is what I need.